# How to reuse cached image in Glide?

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

Is it possible to keep a reference to the loaded image into cache (on disk) and reuse it later in Glide 4?

Let's say I want to load an image like this:

```
Future<Bitmap> future = Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(resourceId).submit(300, 200);
```

I want to save new processed bitmap to disk. Should I use `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)`?

Then in the next activity I want to reuse this new bitmap from disk cache.
How can I do it? Should I use `signature` as a reference to access this bitmap?